# How can I use a stored procedure + repository + unit of work patterns in Entity Framework?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, ef-code-first, repository-pattern, unit-of-work

I have MVC web application project with Entity Framework code first. In this project I am going to use generic repository and unit of work patterns. Plus I want to use stored procedures for get list by and `get-list` methods.

How can I use stored procedures with generic repository and unit of work patterns?

Comment: The code-first approach doesn't support using stored procedures just yet - that's a feature that will be coming in Entity Framework v6 that's supposed to be out later this year

Comment: @marc_s: To be precise, it doesn't support *mapping* stored procedures to .NET methods. *Using* them and wrapping a call to `SqlQuery` (with the SP name as parameter) into a repository method is possible (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj592907). Not the perfect way, but possible...

Comment: @Slauma - Actually, I think you mean is that it doesn't support mapping the EF model to stored procedures.  This is being addressed in v6.  You can map a stored proc to an object, and you can map that sproc to a method (ie wrap it).  But this is largely a manual process in code first.

Comment: @marc_s i googeled  but i cant find any  sample that use store procedure  thanks for edit and your comment

Comment: @marc_s i use ef version 6 but in ef version 6 just you can map crud storeprocedure not any more like getlist or getlistby just crud

Comment: @marc_s why you said  not the perfect way ?do you have any reason ?

Comment: Why would you do this? It is only for reading so what do you get by using UOW?

Answer (score 22):

To your generic repository add

```
public IEnumerable<T> ExecWithStoreProcedure(string query, params object[] parameters)
{
        return _context.Database.SqlQuery<T>(query, parameters);
}
```

And then you can call it with any unitofwork/repository like

```
IEnumerable<Products> products = 
             _unitOfWork.ProductRepository.ExecWithStoreProcedure(
             "spGetProducts @bigCategoryId",
             new SqlParameter("bigCategoryId", SqlDbType.BigInt) { Value = categoryId } 
      );
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but a question in  second section of your answer we implement the method of ExecWithStoreProcedure in genric repository  i think by using unit of work i have to say this  _unitOfWork.ProductRepository.ExecWithStoreProcedure(our query ,parametrs[]); if i think wrong peleas say me

Comment: Sorry you are correct, it should be
`_unitOfWork.ProductRepository.ExecWithStoreProcedure`
T will come from `ProductRepository : GenericRepository<Product>`

Comment: But what if you have an SP that doesn't return the entity your repository maps to? For instance, my SP may return data that joins tables or simply returns an integer value called 'Result'. In that scenario, using the above example with a Product entity would be insufficient and break the Interface Segregation Principle. Any ideas?

Comment: would like to see if there are any responses to the above commment

Comment: This is just calling a stored procedure and this will not adhere to UOW.

Answer (score 12):

**You shouldn't be trying to use SPs with UoW/Repository pattern**, because they are **hard to control** in code and often don't map back to the same entity type. UoW and Repository pattern are better suited to using ADO.NET directly and not Entity Framework, as **EF is already a Repository pattern**. I would suggest CQRS as a better pattern when using SPs. Elaborating on the answer by @sunil and my comment on it, I created a class specifically for handling stored procedures. It's easy to mock and test, too.

```
public class ProcedureManager : IProcedureManager
{
    internal DbContext Context;

    public ProcedureManager(DbContext context)
    {
        Context = context;
    }

    //When you expect a model back (async)
    public async Task<IList<T>> ExecWithStoreProcedureAsync<T>(string query, params object[] parameters)
    {
        return await Context.Database.SqlQuery<T>(query, parameters).ToListAsync();
    }

    //When you expect a model back
    public IEnumerable<T> ExecWithStoreProcedure<T>(string query)
    {
        return Context.Database.SqlQuery<T>(query);
    }

    // Fire and forget (async)
    public async Task ExecuteWithStoreProcedureAsync(string query, params object[] parameters)
    {
        await Context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync(query, parameters);
    }

    // Fire and forget
    public void ExecuteWithStoreProcedure(string query, params object[] parameters)
    {
        Context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(query, parameters);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is just calling a stored procedure and this will not adhere to UOW.

Comment: Of course it won't. SPs cannot adhere to UoW pattern as UoW pattern is for ORMs that track changes and perform operations in bulk. This interface is a useful approach for separating SP execution from ORM logic that can track changes. In answering the OPs question, you shouldn't use SPs with UoW pattern. SPs really aren't suited to the Repository pattern either and are probably better suited to CQRS.

Comment: But the question asked is: *How can I use stored procedures with generic repository and unit of work patterns?*

Comment: And my answer was: You shouldn't.

Comment: I think you should remove your edit because your answer now has false info and people will downvote you. If I were you, I would just include: *UOW with stored procedures need manual transaction handling.* Then continue with your answer as you had before the edit.

Answer (score 2):

For Generic Repository Add this :

```
  public IEnumerable<TEntity> GetdataFromSqlcommand(string command, System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter[] parameter)
    {
        StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        strBuilder.Append($"EXECUTE {command}");
        strBuilder.Append(string.Join(",", parameter.ToList().Select(s => $" @{s.ParameterName}")));

        return Context.Set<TEntity>().FromSql(strBuilder.ToString(), parameter);
    }
```

And you just need to send Stored Procedure name and the array of parameters :

```
public IEnumerable<MainData> GetMainData(Param query)
{
    var param1 = new SqlParameter("param1", query.param1);
    var param2 = new SqlParameter("param2", query.param2);
    return GetdataFromSqlcommand("StoredProcedurename", parameter: new[] { param1, param2 }).ToList();
}
```

Comment: This is just calling a stored procedure and this will not adhere to UOW.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using .net core 3.1, you have to make work around

1. You will create a class that will carry result of stored procedure
2. You will create another partial class from DBcontext and put inside it the previous class
3. You will create `IStoredProcedure` interface and implement it in stored procedure  using generic
4. Inject your stored procedure class in startup class
5. Don't forget to make your result class fields, same as result form stored procedure
6. Execute the stored procedure

Implementation:

**(1)** first step

```
public class TaskPercents
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public long SchoolRepId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

**(2)** second step

```
public partial class SchoolsPartnershipDBContext : DbContext
{
    public virtual DbSet<TaskPercents> TaskPercents { get; set; }
}
```

**(3)** third step

```
public interface IStoredProcedure<T> 
{
    public List<T> ExecuteStored(string query);
}

{
    private SchoolsPartnershipDBContext _context;

    public StoredProcedure(SchoolsPartnershipDBContext Context)
    {
        _context = Context;
    }

    public List<T> ExecuteStored(string query)
    {
        //Context = new SchoolsPartnershipDBContext();
        var r = _context.Set<T>().FromSqlRaw(query);
        return r.ToList();
        // return null;
    }
}
```

Last step

```
        var result = _storedProcedure.ExecuteStored("TaskExecPercentForSchoolRep");
        return result.ToList();
```